# Proving the Irrationality of $\frac{\sin(a \theta)}{\sin(b \theta)}$

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I want to find a real $\theta$ such  $\frac{\sin(a \theta)}{\sin(b \theta)}$ must be irrational for all positive integers $a$ and $b$. How could I go about finding such a $\theta$ and then prove that this $\theta$ satisfies the aforementioned condition for all positive integers?

Comment: Such $\theta$ does not exist because of the case $a=b$.

Comment: Do you really mean for all integers $a, b$ or *for some* integers $a, b$?

Comment: The question I'm trying to answer is what $\theta$ must result in a triangle with irrational sides, given that two of the angles must be a multiple of $\theta.$ Obviously, an isosceles triangle results in a 1:1 ratio for two of the sides, but what about the third side? @player3236

Comment: That seems like a more interesting question, and thus this part (the context!) should be included in the question body. In the case of an isosceles triangle, whether the sides can be all rational depends on the irrationality of $\cos \theta$.

Comment: I think I found the answer. Take the let theta be arccos(e-2) or any other transcendental number in [-1,1] @player3236